# I cannot change alpha value of material. Error in shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

My code to change alpha value:

```
Color color = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        color = new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b, 0.5f);

        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
```

Error I get when trying to change alpha value:

[image]

My Shader File(MultipleUVBlend01):

https://codecollab.io/@proj/OfferChapterBasket#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color in you shader is set to a custom name "_MainColor" so you need to use GetColor() and SetColor().

```
Color color = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.GetColor("_MainColor");
        color = new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b, 0.5f);
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_MainColor", color);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you access `material.color`, behind the scenes Unity is getting & setting the `_Color` property of the shader. Unity is throwing this error as the shader you are using doesn't have a `_Color` property but rather `_MainColor`

To resolve this, you have a few options:

- In the shader, add the `[MainColor]` attribute before `_MainColor`'s declaration
- Directly access the property you want to adjust with `material.GetColor("_MainColor")` and `material.SetColor("_MainColor")`